# Set Default Text Option in AngularJS Dropdownlost

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs dropdownlist using ng-options

```
<select ng-options="perlocation.name for perlocation in locations" ng-model="locationDropdown">
```

My dropdown list loads fine but the selected option 0 is empty and i want to replace it with "Please Select One"

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

How do i do this? All the examples i have seen online doesnt seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the angular documentation for [`select`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/select) it states

> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set
>   to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This
>   element will then represent the null or "not selected" option. See
>   example below for demonstration.

Which means you can do this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-init="arr=[1,2,3]">
    <select ng-model="val" ng-options="x for x in arr">
      <option value="">Please select an option</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Val: {{val}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Initialize `$scope.locationDropdown = 'Please Select One'` as default

or

```
<select ng-options="perlocation.name for perlocation in locations" ng-model="locationDropdown">
  <option> Please Select One </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not good because then `'Please Select One'` becomes a valid option, which it should not be.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg it depend upon him how he want and select is itself a directive and we adding html inside in it.I don't know may be it's a right things

Comment: It does not depend. You never want "please select one" to be an actual option. Also you're edit doesn't even work, please read the angular docs.